# In F#, The expression was expected to have type 'Nullable<DateTime>' but here has type 'DateTime'

Tags: f#

I have the following function in F# which returns data from a local database:

```
let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
        async {
            let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
                Visit.lastName = q.lastname
                firstName = q.firstname
                birthDate = q.birthdate 
                appointmentTime = q.appointment_time
                tservice = q.service_time
                postingTime = q.posting_time
                chartNumber = q.chart_number
                })                  
          }
          |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Where Visit is defined as:

```
type Visit = {
    lastName : string
    firstName : string
    birthDate : Nullable<DateTime>
    appointmentTime : Nullable<DateTime>
    tservice : Nullable<DateTime>
    postingTime : Nullable<DateTime>
    chartNumber : Nullable<int>
    }
```

Now the downloaded q.birthdate from the database is non-null, but the Visit definition has it as nullable. Hence, the following error results:

```
The expression was expected to have type
  'Nullable<DateTime>'
but here has type
   'DateTime'
```

How do I keep the definition of Visit the same without changing the database and fix the error?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly make a `Nullable` value like this: `Nullable q.birthdate`.

Comment: FYI this is becoming implicit in F# 5